# NXException when removing and then adding an itme to UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

When I remove an object from a list and try to add a new one in I get this error

`2020-01-24 14:40:26.692343+1300 HappyDays[25416:1017241] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0. The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (3) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (0), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (1 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'`

I see other issues similar to this but I've tried implementing those solutions . ([Similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53061782/invalid-update-invalid-number-of-rows-in-section-1) , [another similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44242154/nsinternalinconsistencyexception-tableview-row-deletion))

Sections of my code:
Selecting the cell to delete if from the table

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {      
    activeObjectives.actives.remove(at: indexPath.row)
    tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .left)
}
```

Adding a new object to the table by tapping a button

```
@IBAction func getGoals(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let newRowIndex = activeObjectives.actives.count
    activeObjectives.setRandomGoalToActive(allObjectiveList: allGoalsArray)

    addActiveGoalToactiveObjectives()

    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: newRowIndex, section: 0)
    let indexPaths = [indexPath]
    activeGoalDisplay.insertRows(at: indexPaths, with: .automatic)

}
```

In case it's also needed, here is my addActiveGoalToactiveObjectives function called in the above

```
func addActiveGoalToactiveObjectives() {
    for goal in allGoalsArray.goalsList {
        if goal.isActive == true && activeObjectives.actives.contains(goal) == false {
            activeObjectives.actives.append(goal)
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance, any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: How do you calculate `numberOfRowsInSection`?

Comment: The code crashes if no object (or more than one object) is added in `addActiveGoalToactiveObjectives`.

Comment: I calculate it by getting the number in the activeObjects array

`// Set the number of rows to the amount of goals in the activeObjectives array
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return activeObjectives.actives.count
    }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. I wasn't setting an object value to false when removing it from the list. Now when I remove them I set the object to inactive.

````
        activeObjectives.actives[indexPath.row].setInactive()
        activeObjectives.actives.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .left) 
    }```
````